# Sqlite order by date in array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table that contains entries and another table that contains the ids of the saved/favorites of those entries.

I want to get the entries that have their ids listed in the favorites and order it by the added_date in the favorites table.

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id IN (SELECT favorite_id FROM favorites ORDER BY date_added)
```

This query does get the correct entries, but it does not order them correctly.

How can I order the `entries` by the `favorites.added_date` column?

Comment: ORDER BY in the sub-select makes no sense. Put it outside instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use `JOIN` also with the `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM entries E
JOIN favorites F ON F.favorite_id = E.id
ORDER BY F.date_added ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A In clause for a subquery is equal to an inner join .. but (normally) more  fast 
and if the order by for a subquery in a `IN` clause have not sense  the inner join allow you an orderd result

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN favorites f  ON e.id = f.favorite_id 
order by f.date_added
```